# Prove that for every polynomial $w(\lambda)=(-1)^{n}\lambda^{n}+a_{n-1} \lambda^{n-1}+...+a_{1}\lambda +a_{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that for every polynomial $w(\lambda)=(-1)^{n}\lambda^{n}+a_{n-1} \lambda^{n-1}+...+a_{1}\lambda +a_{0}$ with coefficients in the body of $ K $ exist matrix $A \in M_{nxn}(K)$ such that $w(\lambda)$ is a characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$.

I had one task where $w(\lambda)$ was a characteristic polynomial of some $A$ but I don't have idea how to prove that always exist such a matrix.
I have $det(A-\lambda I)=(-1)^{n}\lambda^{n}+a_{n-1} \lambda^{n-1}+...+a_{1}\lambda +a_{0}$ and it is difficult to find a formula for $ A $ from this to prove that $A$ exist.
Please, give me some tips...

Comment: Try the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).